# Force ToggleButton to stop writing into my local memory file

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-intent

I have a variable **MyFinalPressure** which is populated with sensor data from the sensors pressure. If **MyFinalPressure** is `==` to 4000 (4000 points or 40 sec) then stop writing to local storage.
But it looks like when I debug the code, it hits the boolean **MaxPoints** and is still writing. I wonder if my logic is wrong or not.

Could you please help me out.

```
  public Boolean Store = false;
  Boolean MaxPoints = false;

  if (activity.Store) {
     activity.writeToFile(MyFinalPressure);//MyFinalPressure is float of one dimension array or stream of array. 
  }
  if (MyFinalPressure==4000){  //this conditon, am trying to stop wrting to local memory. 
     activity.MaxPoints = true;
  }

FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;

 //method to write into local memory. 
public void writeToFile(final float MyFinalPressure) {
    Log.d(TAG, "writeToFile.");
    String finalData;
    finalData = String.valueOf(MyFinalPressure);


    try {
        // true here for 'append'
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, true);

        String Space = " ";
        byte[] convert = Space.getBytes();

        fileOutputStream.write(finalData.getBytes());

        fileOutputStream.write(convert);
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

 //write to file.
    StartWriting = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.startWriting);
    StartWriting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (StartWriting.isChecked()) {
                Store = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Starts writing into (Message.txt) file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                if (!StartWriting.isChecked()|| MaxPoints==true) {  //here - this is wrong logic to stop writing to my file.
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Stored at myAppFile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String finalData1;
                    finalData1 = String.valueOf(fileOutputStream);
                    Log.i(TAG, "of_writes: " + finalData1);
                    //    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data_write_number:  " + finalData1.length(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Store = false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take out !StartWriting.isChecked()

Because of the above if statement StartWriting.isChecked() will always be false.  Then because you are checking for "!StartWriting.isChecked()" it will always enter the statement.